# Converting data type varchar to float

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I just need to update some cells in my database by calculating some figures. But i dont know why there is an exception still popin up: Converting data type varchar to float. Any thoughts what could be wrong ? im watching on this for like 2 hours ...

```
        Item oldItem = new Item();
        Item newItem = new Item();

        oldItem = cmbItems.SelectedItem as Item;

        newItem.PredaneMnozstvo = oldItem.PredaneMnozstvo + 1;
        newItem.Mnozstvo = oldItem.Mnozstvo - 1;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAkcia.Text))
            newItem.HrubyZisk = oldItem.PredajnaCena - oldItem.NakupnaCena - double.Parse(txtAkcia.Text);
        else
            newItem.HrubyZisk = oldItem.PredajnaCena - oldItem.NakupnaCena;
        newItem.CistyZisk = Math.Round(newItem.HrubyZisk * 0.81,2);

        broker.UpdatePredal(newItem, oldItem);

    public void UpdatePredal(Item newItem, Item oldItem)
    {
    try
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE Sklad SET Mnozstvo= '"+newItem.Mnozstvo+"', PredaneMnozstvo= '"+newItem.PredaneMnozstvo+"',HrubyZisk= '"+newItem.HrubyZisk.ToString()+"', CistyZisk='"+newItem.CistyZisk+"' WHERE ID=" + oldItem.Id;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            connection.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eX.Message);
        }
     }
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Which line throws exception? Also you shouldn't concatenate SQL command and use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: Please show the full exception, we're not psychic.

Comment: after ExecutingnonQuery and i dunno why cuz my types are all good no need to convert anything ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that one of values concatenated to query string should be a float, hence shouldn't be wrapped around single quotes (like this one for example : `'"+newItem.HrubyZisk.ToString()+"'`).

Anyway, better fix to your problem is using parameterized query, that will save you from sql injection and complexity of converting specific data type (such as DateTime, Decimal, etc) to it's string representation that is valid according to database specific culture. For example :

```
try
{
    string sql = "UPDATE Sklad SET Mnozstvo= @Mnozstvo, PredaneMnozstvo= @PredaneMnozstvo, HrubyZisk= @HrubyZisk, CistyZisk=@CistyZisk WHERE ID=@ID";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mnozstvo", newItem.Mnozstvo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PredaneMnozstvo", newItem.PredaneMnozstvo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HrubyZisk", newItem.HrubyZisk);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CistyZisk", newItem.CistyZisk);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", oldItem.Id);

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception eX)
{
    MessageBox.Show(eX.Message);
}
```

Comment: when i tried this exception pop up that "must declare the scalar variable @Mnozstvo"

Comment: at which line you got that exception? shouldn't be at this line : `string sql = ...`. That's just plain string declaration **without** concatenation.

Comment: its after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: hmm... codes above should work fine as far as I can see. variable `@Mnozstvo` already declared at this line : `.AddWithValue("@Mnozstvo", newItem.Mnozstvo);`